# Update all column values to boolean in room android?

Tags: android, android-room

I have database table as

```
@Entity
internal data class NotificationEntity(
@PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "notification_id") val notificationId: String,
val title: String,
val body: String?,
@ColumnInfo(name = "is_actionable") val isActionable: Boolean,
@ColumnInfo(name = "created_at") val createdAt: Instant,
@ColumnInfo(name = "is_read") val isRead: Boolean = false)
```

I want to update all the column values of `isRead`  to `true`

I am using the following query but it isn't working.

```
@Query("UPDATE NotificationEntity SET is_read = 'true'")
suspend fun updateReadStatus()
```

Is it correct or not?

Comment: try removing quotes around true.

Comment: @NatarajKR removing quotes will and give error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The boolean values are mapped to the integer internally. So you should use

```
@Query("UPDATE NotificationEntity SET is_read = 1")
```